# Writing a reusable ajax (Jquery) function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to write a reusable ajax function with jquery. I have so far have:

```
function doAjaxprocess(url, params, type) {

  $.ajax({
    data : params,
    url : url,
    type : type,
    dataType : 'json'
  });
}
```

How can I incoporated to return complete, sucess, error and done. Not all calls require done.

Thanks

Comment: Just return the `$.ajax` promise

Answer (score 0):

Prepare methods for success, error and done.

```
function handleSuccess(response){
  ...
}
function handleError(response){
  ...
}
function handleDone(response){
  ...
}
```

Then, add parameter for success, error and done methods to **doAjaxprocess** method.

```
function doAjaxprocess(url, params, type, success, error, done) {
    $.ajax({
       ... ,
       success: success,
       error: error,
       done: done
       });
}
```

And call **doAjaxprocess** method like this:

```
doAjaxprocess(.., handleSuccess, handleError, handleDone);
```

Thats all.

Answer (score -1):

```
var id      = 22; 
var content = "here is my content";
var data = {'id':id,'content',content}
jQuery.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "post.php",  
    data: data,  
    success: function(answer){
        console.log(answer);
        } 
    }
});`
```